# gnus: doesn't delete articles over IMAP

Tags: gnus, email, imap

As Gnus documentation suggests, pressing `B` in the Summary Plugged mode deletes an email. So Gnus doesn't display them, but they're still visible in Web-based gmail client. Please note that I did set `Auto-Expunge off - Wait for the client to update the server.` and `Immediately delete the message forever` in my gmail account settings.

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code from https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org

```
;; @see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Expiring-Mail.html
;; press 'E' to expire email
(nnmail-expiry-target "nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Trash")
```

The mail will be moved to Trash folder.

Comment: thanks for comment. I added `(setq nnmail-expiry-target "nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Trash")` since otherwise Gnus was complaining about the error. Now, pressing `E` marks email as expired. In order to move it in Trash right away, I also `(setq nnmail-expiry-wait "immediate")`. Does this look right to you?

Comment: `(setq nnmail-expiry-wait 'immediate)`

Comment: Can move it to the trash right away *B* *m* nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Trash